# how to loop through list in etree.findall()

Tags: python, lxml, python-3.3

I would like to make the follwing work but having a hard time. How can I loop though `ns` in the for loop?

```
ns = ['one', 'two']

tree = etree.parse(file) 
for items in tree.findall('.//' + ns):
    print(items)
```

EDIT:
Looking for a solution without nested for loops.

EDIT:

```
   ns = ['{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}identifier[@{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type]',
           '{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}title',
           '{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}description',
           '{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}subject',
           '{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}type',
           '{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}educationLevel']
   tree = etree.parse(file)
   for leaf in tree.xpath('//*[local-name()="record"]'):
       for items in leaf.findall('.//' + ns[0]):
           print(items)
```

Comment: Which one do you use: `lxml` / `xml.etree.ElementTree`?

Comment: I am using lxml.etree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath):

```
from lxml import etree

nsmap = {
    'xmlns': 'http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/',
    'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/',
    'dct': 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/',
    'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
}
ns = [
    'dc:identifier[@xsi:type]',
    'dc:title',
    'dc:description',
    'dc:subject',
    'dc:type',
    'dct:educationLevel'
]
tree = etree.parse(file)
xpath = '|'.join('.//xmlns:record//{}'.format(n) for n in ns)
for items in tree.xpath(xpath, namespaces=nsmap):
    print(items)
```

Comment: getting `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`

Comment: @user1991424, Can you post (or upload to somewhere) the xml used?

Comment: Sure, it is pretty large. 2.6mb.

Comment: @user1991424, Upload the xml somewhere and let me know the url.

Comment: @user1991424, What is the actual value of `ns`? There seems no `one` or `two` tag exist.

Comment: by the way, the ns in my op was a generic one. I will post an edit with my actual code.

Comment: seems to only print all instances of `{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}identifier`

Comment: Very nice but I think the problem with this is that it joins everything I want to find into one string, getting `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix`. print(xpath) gives `.//xmlns:record//dc:identifier[@xsi:type]|.//xmlns:record//dc:title|.//xmlns:record//dc:description|.//xmlns:record//dc:subject|.//xmlns:record//dc:type|.//xmlns:record//dct:educationLevel` as one long string.

Comment: @user1991424, Which version of lxml do you use? It works on lxml 3.2.3.

Comment: @user1991424, Did you specify `namespace=nsmap`?

Comment: Ahhh. I only update the loop not ns and nsmap. Works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: By the way is the a benefit to ussing CSSelector vs xpath? I didn't get a chance to try that code

Comment: @user1991424, cssselect is simpler in most case. cssselector is convert to xpath internally. I didn't experimented cssselector with namespaces; No example. Sorry.

Comment: Thats fine just wanted to know if there were any advantages it had over xpath, like speed. The new xpath you posted seems to run a lot slower than my original